# Input type Password with Autocomplete on. val() coming blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field :

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="on" required="" class="ui-state-valid">
```

When page initially loads and autocomplete hits, the $("#password").val() returns a "". Even when there is value inserted by the autocomplete.

This is causing issues with the custom placeholder.

I need to know why the value is blank. I have other input fields in the page which work fine with the autocomplete.

Comment: try required only or required="true"

Comment: Probably your script requestings it's val() gets triggered before the autocomplete fills in the field? And as Ker mentioned, it's `required` without `=""`

Comment: I changed the required="" to required. Didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As of Internet Explorer11, the autocomplete property is no longer
>   supported for input type=password fields.
>
> The AutoComplete feature is highlighted in the Using AutoComplete in
>   HTML Forms overview.
>
> When AutoComplete is enabled, suggestions are provided for the value
>   of a text field. Suggested values are mapped values based on the name
>   attribute or vCard schema specified by the vcard_name attribute.
>
> If AutoComplete is disabled, values are not stored and suggested
>   values are not presented.
>
> Values in input type=password elements can be mapped for AutoComplete;
>   however, the ability to store this information can be disabled in the
>   browser, and the user is prompted for a confirmation before the value
>   is stored.
>
> Information provided by the AutoComplete feature is not exposed to the
>   object model, and is not visible to a Web page until the user selects
>   one of the suggestions as a value for the text field.

ref :- [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms533486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I found the exact same article when I was looking for a manual to see if the syntax was correct :p What I also found: "Chrome seems to be ignoring the autocomplete attribute as of version 34." (http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/autocomplete-off/)

Comment: i'm using mozilla 31, chrome 36 and IE 11. Password fails everywhere except mozilla.

Comment: i tried triggering a dummy click event on the input field, focus() .. nothing seems to work.